# R giving error when attempting map algebra

Tags: raster, r, error, map-algebra

I'm trying to manipulate some downloaded rasters using R, and keep getting the same error when I try to do any type of map algebra.

The example below uses a raster file downloaded from http://www.csc.noaa.gov/digitalcoast/data/ccapregional/ geotiff and .grd files, regardless of whether I downloaded them or generated them previously.

```
require(raster)
test1=raster("nh_2006_ccap_land_cover.img")
test2=test1+1
```

Gives the error:

```
Error in matrix(unlist(ini), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
In addition: There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

On the other hand, I'm not encountering problems with map algebra for rasters generated on the fly.  So I'm not having any problems with this example from the documentation:

```
r1 <- raster(ncols=10, nrows=10)
r1[] <- runif(ncell(r1))
r2 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r1) / ncell(r1) )
r3 <- r1 + r2
r2 <- r1 / 10
r3 <- r1 * (r2 - 1 + r1^2 / r2)
plot(r3)
```

What's going on here?

Comment: What did the warnings say?  Have you at least been able to plot the raster dataset?

Comment: The warnings seem to be a bunch of repetitions of "In writeBin(v, x@file@con, size = x@file@dsize) :
  problem writing to connection"

Ok, this is almost certainly related to the fact that I seem to have eaten up all of the storage space on my hard drive.  Now I have a different thing to troubleshoot.  I'll come back and close this if resolving the disk space issue solves it.

Comment: I have the same issue when I run remotely in parallel in a linux supercomputer. Did you figure out how to solve the issue?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/71217)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that I had run out of space to write to disk, and the map algebra commands I was using were attempting to generate and write large temporary raster files.

Comment: but your answer is not exactly a solution because large temporary rasters still need to be used.