# Error using 'extract' to extract landsat pixel values from training data

Tags: r, classification, extract

I'm getting an error with a line of code that I've run successfully in the past. My goal is to extract landsat pixel values from training data polygon shapefile for classification. Here's my code up until the error:

##### Load, stack, and brick Landsat rasters

```
all_landsat_bands<-list.files("E:/NorthBahamas_GDB/WorkingFiles/POST_DORIAN/Train/L2SP_POST", pattern =".tif$", full.names=TRUE)
landsat_stack <-stack(all_landsat_bands)
landsat_brick <- brick(landsat_stack)
```

###### **'stack'**: *Links several raster objects written to different files*, **'brick'**: *Creates one multi-layer file*

##### Assign column headers to Landsat brick

```
names(landsat_brick)
vecnames=c("b2","b3","b4","b5","b6","b7", "NDVI")
names(landsat_brick)=vecnames
```

##### Load training data

```
All_CAT<-shapefile("E:/NorthBahamas_GDB/WorkingFiles/POST_DORIAN/Train/POST_MapV5_15.shp")
```

##### Check CRS and projection of landsat and training data

```
crs(All_CAT)
crs(landsat_brick)
```

##### Set the CRS of training data to match the landsat brick

```
ALLCAT_prj <- spTransform(All_CAT, crs(landsat_brick))
```

##### Extract the landsat pixel values from training data

```
ext2<-extract(landsat_brick, ALLCAT_prj, df = TRUE)
```

The error I'm getting here with the 'extract' function is **Error in res[i] <- readBin(x@file@con, what = dtype, n = 1, size = dsize, : replacement has length zero**

I obviously still have a lot to learn with spatial analysis in R but was unable to find a solution through troubleshooting.

Do you have any ideas on what could be causing this error?

This line of code worked just yesterday. The only thing that changed was the input rasters.

Comment: Hard to tell without some information about your data - can you plot the brick and the `ALLCAT_prj` on a map and show that? Or share the data files? Or at least show us some summary info of your data - bounding boxes, CRS, number of polygons etc?

Comment: I would note that, even if there were a bug, it will likely never be addressed as the `raster` package is no longer in active development. Not long ago I had some very strange behavior with brick objects so, I think there may be something amiss with the object class. So, either just use `raster::stack` or, mover over to `terra`, the package that is replacing `raster`. Since you are learning, I would recommend learning the new interface and not the old. The raster/brick difference is related to on disk performance and not all that important a distinction, you would want a stack anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might check for insufficient disk space, guessing from the error thrown by `readBin`: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/108360/201201 (or rather switch to package {terra} as Jeffrey Evans suggested).